# Java для Web.

Tags: java

Работа с Jsp и Сервлетами требует от меня знаний html и css?
Собираюсь идти на стажировку, но не хочется заниматься версткой, это совсем другая область и если ею заниматься, то основательно, т.к. там много своих фишек, над которыми можно надолго застрять.
Или лучше попробовать найти стажировку под desktop?(если такое с Java вообще реально)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно, Java developer рисует весьма приблизительные страницы на JSP, потом сажают верстальщика, который доводит страницы до нужной кондиции. Тем не менее знать HTML/JavaScript все равно надо.

Java desktop раз в 10, а то поболее менее востребована чем Java Web, так что делайте выводы.

Answer (score 4):

Работа с jsp сама по себе требует базовых знаний html.(Да и вообще сложно представить веб-разработчика без этих знаний)
Вообще, если Вы не любите изучать новые инструменты - то Вам вообще не стоит идти программистом. Работа на java в любой области подразумевает изучение новый фреймворков или разработкой своих.
К примеру о других технологиях, на данный момент в web часто используется ajax запрос (знание js необходимо), ajax в свою очередь используется с xml(знание xml необходимо) или json... там и до xPath недалеко, и xsl может каким то чудом подкрасться.
Слов страшных и разных я много знаю, но все они не так страшны. Важно уяснить что Вы хотите делать. Работать на фронте или в бек'энде. Дело в том что верстальщики единственное чем занимаются - верстка, их основные инструменты js+css(при том как правило js направлен на изменение вида отображения содержимого на странице). Мастером js Вы можете не становится, но обычную клиентскую валидацию должны уметь делать, всё остальное приходит с опытом.
P.S. По поводу разработки под десктоп ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно для WEB UI  в корпоративных джава приложениях используются готовые фреймворки компонентов либо настроеные единые стили. Но минимальные знания Html и JavaScript нужны хотя бы чтобы вы могли манипулировать этими компонентами на странице - например послать ajax запрос.